# Verificar se diretório é um repositório com LibGit2Sharp (C#)

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

Estou começando a estudar C# por isso meu conhecimento é bem limitado. Estou utilizando a biblioteca [`LibGit2Sharp`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki) e gostaria de verificar se um diretório informado é um repositório. A documentação deles ainda não está completa, por isso estou com dificuldades.

Segue meu código:

```
static void SetRepository()
{
    bool seted = false;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Informe o caminho do repositório:");
        String dir = Console.ReadLine();
        EmptyLine();

        // Talvez a verificação devesse ser aqui... Mas não sei como descobrir se é um repositório GIT ou não
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(dir.Trim())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Diretório inválido.");
            EmptyLine();
            Pause();
        }
        else
        {
            // Não estou sabendo como verificar se é um repositório aqui!!
            SetArg("repository", dir);
            repo = new Repository(dir);
            seted = true;

        }

    } while (!seted);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar:

```
Repository.IsValid(dir);
```

O Código fonte da classe `Repository` [está aqui](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/Repository.cs)

Traduzindo livremente o texto da documentação do método, temos o seguinte:

> Verifica se o parâmetro `path` indica um repositório Git válido.
>
> **Parâmetros**:
>
> `path`: O caminho do repositório git para verificar, pode ser tanto o caminho para um diretório git (para repositórios não vazios seria o diretório ".git" dentro do diretório de trabalho) ou o caminho para o diretório de trabalho.
>
> **Retorna**:
>
> `true` se o repositório pode ser resolvido por esse caminho; `false` caso contrário

Comment: Valeu, funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Dei uma melhorada na resposta, inserindo o texto da documentação, para que fique para futuras referências.

Answer (score 1):

[Aparentemente é usado o comando `git-ls-tree`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/Git-ls-tree). Se houver algo dentro, é um repositório:

```
using (var repo = new Repository(dir))
{
    var tree = Repository.Lookup<Tree>("sha");
    if (tree != null && tree.items.Count > 0)
        Console.WriteLine("É um repositório.");
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Cigano, mas a resposta do Marcus é melhor, enfim, uma dúvida que eu tenho é sobre esse "sha" isso é um valor constante, ou nome do meu commit? Vi isso na documentação deles mas não entendi.

Comment: Realmente a outra resposta é melhor. "sha" seria o Id do Commit, pelo que eu entendi.